# JWT token validation in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt

I'm writing an API in ASP.NET that exposes two endpoints: one to generate a JWT token and other to validate a given token.

The token generation seems to work fine:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Token()
        {
            var headerAuth = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            if (headerAuth.ToString().StartsWith("Basic"))
            {
                var credValue = headerAuth.ToString().Substring("Basic".Length).Trim();
                var usernameAndPassEnc = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(credValue));
                var usernameAndPass = usernameAndPassEnc.Split(':');

                LdapAuthentication ldap = new LdapAuthentication();

                if (ldap.IsAuthenticated(usernameAndPass[0], usernameAndPass[1]))
                {
                    var claimsData = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usernameAndPass[0]) };
                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret"));
                    var signInCred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);
                    var tokenString = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: "http://my.website.com",
                        audience: "http://my.tokenissuer.com",
                        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
                        claims: claimsData,
                        signingCredentials: signInCred
                        );

                    var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenString);
                    return Ok(token);
                }
            }

            return BadRequest("Bad request");
        }
```

But I don't know how to validate a given token, in ASP.NET Core I implement it in this whay (which works fine):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "http://my.website.com",
                    ValidAudience = "http://my.tokenissuer.com",
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("secret"))
                };
            });
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

So, how can I validate a JWT token in ASP.NET?

Comment: What you mean by validate JWT Token ?

Comment: I mean check that no one has modified the token. 
Verify the signature like in the JWT webpage debugger https://jwt.io/

Comment: you usually don't have a separate endpoint for that but decorate your API with `[Authorize]` and let the middleware do the work for you. I recommend reading [Taiseer Joudeh's blog](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) as a good introduction on how to do it in ASP.NET

Comment: You have also the official MS Documentation : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/06/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Yeah, but I want to implement all of the authentication logic in a separate service which will be deployed independently. And various applications will use that authentication.

Comment: @Juan : in that scenario you have an Authoriization server that issues the JWT but the resource server(s) would still validate the JWT on it's own.

Comment: @jps And how can I validate that in ASP.NET?

Comment: @Juan: probably the new answer is already the solution or see above in the linked blog. You would need to share the secret between authorization server and resource server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that either you can write a middleware or use the existing Authorize filter and override it. Use the following way to validate the token

```
    public static bool ValidateToken(string authToken) // Retrieve token from request header
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var validationParameters = this.GetValidationParameters();

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        IPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        return true;
    }

    private static TokenValidationParameters GetValidationParameters()
    {
        return new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningToken = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.BinarySecretSecurityToken(symmetricKey), //Key used for token generation
            ValidIssuer = issuerName,
            ValidAudience = allowedAudience,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true
        };
    }
```