# How to create Startup file in Web ASP.NET (.NET Framework)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, api, jwt

I have a website build in VB.NET as ASP.NET (.NET Framework) so it's not a CORE application.

The website has lot's of API's build in WebApi 2 inside it and now i was going to make an authentication API via JWT, actually i have yet a Controller which return JWT token but now i have to validate it...

As i've read on the web i have to validate it throw a middleware like OWIN so i need to add the following method inside Startup class

```
Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(New JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions With {
            .AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters() With {
                .ValidateIssuer = True,
                .ValidateAudience = True,
                .ValidateIssuerSigningKey = True,
                .ValidIssuer = "url",
                .ValidAudience = "url",
                .IssuerSigningKey = New SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my_secret_key_12345"))
            }
        })
    End Sub
End Class
```

But the issue is that by right-clicking the project and by > adding new element the Startup class doesn't exist...

So how can i create one? As i've read the project must be .NET Core to use Owin Startup class.. so should i rebuild all my project in Core or i can anyway find a way to authenticate JWT token without it?

Comment: This should give a start for your further researches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407749/jwt-token-validation-in-asp-net

Comment: In ASP.NET you can add a global.asax file and handle the Application_Start method.  I'm not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Web Api - Startup.cs doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076150/asp-net-web-api-startup-cs-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Owin startup class to a .NET Framework project by using the following attribute

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(myNamespace.Startup))]

namespace myNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// OWIN startup class, automatically starts when app starts
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```

This should work in vb .net by using this syntax

```
<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(myNamespace.Startup))]
```

Just add a regular class called Startup to your project and this should work.